# Homebrew Install Specific Version of Formula

Tags: kubernetes, homebrew, kubectl

Specifically `kubernetes-cli`. I have 1.12.0 installed. I need 1.11.x, but I don't have that installed.

I've reviewed and tried every answer in this thread and nothing worked: [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

I've tried `brew search` but there are no tapped versions:

```
~ brew search kubernetes-cli
==> Formulae
kubernetes-cli ✔
```

I've tried `brew versions` but that command has been removed:

```
~ brew versions 
Error: Unknown command: versions
```

I've tried `brew install kubernetes-cli@1.11.0` and .1 and .2:

```
~ brew install kubernetes-cli@1.11.0
Error: No available formula with the name "kubernetes-cli@1.11.0" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

`brew switch` requires that I have the older version installed, which I don't.

```
~ brew switch kubernetes-cli 1.11.0
Error: kubernetes-cli does not have a version "1.11.0" in the Cellar.
kubernetes-cli installed versions: 1.12.0
```

Comment: Exactly not answer to this question, but if anybody wants to install a specific version of kubernetes-cli, following steps in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/ is much easier than any of the answers mentioned below.

Comment: brew doesn't generally support old package installation any more so you may be better off using something like https://macports.org, https://github.com/LnL7/nix-darwin, or https://pkgsrc.joyent.com

Answer (score 31):

1. Go to homebrew git repo: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/
2. Identify the commit specific to kubernetes 1.11.x version
3. Go to `Formula` folder
4. Open raw version of `kubernetes-cli.rb` file
5. Copy the raw link of the file
   `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/3e8f5503dde7069c5ff49b82d5e1576e6ebe3a5d/Formula/kubernetes-cli.rb`
6. Run `brew install <raw_link>`

Comment: I used `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/41764e07727d9a86b0f8a077117dc7876ca294c4/Formula/kubernetes-cli.rb` and these instructions to install v.1.11.3.

Comment: I used the combination of this and the answer from @Erik K below to install an earlier version of kubernetes-helm. Erik's answer should be incorporated into this one in place of the "Identify the commit" step.

Comment: _rdump_ has made a real effort to collect helm commit links for previous kubectl versions: [https://gist.github.com/rdump/b79a63084b47f99a41514432132bd408#example-install-commands](https://gist.github.com/rdump/b79a63084b47f99a41514432132bd408#example-install-commands)

Comment: How to get raw file from a specific commit?

Comment: Apparently, the recent homebrew version removed the support to install via a raw link. `Invalid usage: Installation of activemq from a GitHub commit URL is unsupported!`

Comment: I installed with `brew install kubernetes-cli@1.22`. I was getting:

brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/75b367efca10dece21b2d68c55f45f6f0320d56f/Formula/kubernetes-cli.rb
Running `brew update --preinstall`...
Error: Installation of kubernetes-cli from a GitHub commit URL is unsupported! `brew extract kubernetes-cli` to a stable tap on GitHub instead.

Comment: You can look at this guide: https://cmichel.io/how-to-install-an-old-package-version-with-brew/

Answer (score 24):

I dont have enough rep to make a comment on the answer that helped me. So writing here to be more specific about point 2 from @urpalreloaded

1. `brew search --pull-request kubernetes-cli@1.11.0`
2. It will say that it did not find the cask but should give you a link to a closed pull request that matches the version you searched for. Follow the link to the pull request and the follow steps 3-5.
3. `brew unlink kubernetes-cli`
4. `brew install <raw-link>`

FWIW, I think brew doesnt keep versions because it will make the repo too big? This workaround is inconvenient and perhaps they could find a way around this issue on their end?

Comment: Remember to give the url of the RAW file. otherwise you will end up with syntax errors when running brew install.

Comment: Step 1 returns `==> Formulae
kubernetes-cli@1.22` for me...

Comment: seems you need to add `--pull-request` . will update the answer

Answer (score 3):

The above answers were really useful but when I tried to install Carthage 0.30.1 on my Sierra 10.12.6 machine I got a SHA256 mismatch error:

```
$ brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ilovezfs/homebrew-core/8c93668a451087611b2247cafe02ad6f867daed6/Formula/carthage.rb --force-bottle
######################################################################## 100.0%
Warning: carthage 0.32.0 is available and more recent than version 0.30.1.
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/carthage-0.30.1.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
Error: SHA256 mismatch
```

and then it failed to build from source due to latest Sierra Xcode not supporting the new Xcode build system.

What worked for me was to directly install from the bottle (the url is shown in first `brew install <raw url>` output):

```
brew install https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/carthage-0.30.1.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

For `kubernetes-cli` specifically (and if you don't care about patch versions - the `x` in `1.11.x`), you can just use:

```
brew install kubernetes-cli@1.11
```

And it will complete with the latest `x` available.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as dsjapan and what worked for me was changing to high sierra:

```
brew unlink carthage
brew install https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/carthage-0.30.1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to both upgrade and downgrade any formula that's been disabled due to deprecation.
(basically I followed [this guide](https://www.lyc4n.com/blog/2022/09/16/installing-unmaintained-brew-package.html) and set an additional [brew environment variable](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#environment))

In my case I did the following to upgrade from 1.22.16 to 1.22.17 (latest before deprecation):

1. Run:

```bash
brew edit kubernetes-cli@1.22
```

2. Comment this line that begins with `disable! date`:

```rb
# disable! date: "2022-10-28", because: :deprecated_upstream
```

3. Run:

```bash
HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 brew upgrade kubernetes-cli@1.22
```

To roll back or generally install any other version, continue with these steps instead:

2. Replace all lines with [all the lines from the version that you want](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/4fdbbb1d630bb0766239a600415e297ebe51708c/Formula/kubernetes-cli%401.22.rb), which can easily be found via the [commit history](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commits/master/Formula/kubernetes-cli%401.22.rb) (once in commit click `...` -> `View file`) or:

```bash
brew log kubernetes-cli@1.22
```

3. Run:

```bash
HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 brew reinstall kubernetes-cli@1.22
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Apr 2022:

The easiest way I found was to create a [new tap](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/155#discussioncomment-133894).

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I installed older version of kubectl (1.27.4):

```
brew unlink kubernetes-cli
brew tap-new $USER/local-kubernetes-cli
brew extract --version=1.27.4 kubernetes-cli $USER/local-kubernetes-cli
brew install kubernetes-cli@1.27.4
```

The installation took several minutes and during it I've encountered an error about `md5sha1sum` being locked and thus, kubectl can't be installed, because the package needs to be downgraded.
Fixed with the following command:

```
brew unlink md5sha1sum
```

Thanks to yuser **bertonc96** for the link to the guide.